# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@uye_yasi' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Im trying to insert data into my database using C# lang and show it with DataGridView on a Windows Form.But it gives me that specific error:

**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@uye_yasi' to data type int**

Im sure I wrote all of the column names correctly.There is one exception and its ID.Its Primary Key,Not Null and Auto Increment.

*Connection String*

```
SqlConnection baglan = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CASPER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=kutuphane;Integrated Security=True");
```

*The listing method to show on DataGridView;  (works without any problem)*

```
 public void listele() 
 {
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    baglan.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from uyeler",baglan);
    da.Fill(ds1);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
    baglan.Close();
 }
```

*Codes on form_load event*

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listele();

    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
    dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Adı";
    dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Soyadı";
    dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Yaşı";
    dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Adresi";
    dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Telefonu";
    dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Mail Adresi";
}
```

*Codes in CellContentClick event for DataGridView*

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int satir = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

    textAd.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[satir].Cells["uye_adi"].Value.ToString();
    textSoyad.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[satir].Cells["uye_soyadi"].Value.ToString();
    textYas.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[satir].Cells["uye_yasi"].Value.ToString();
    textAdres.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[satir].Cells["uye_adresi"].Value.ToString();
    textTelefon.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[satir].Cells["uye_telefonu"].Value.ToString();
    textMail.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[satir].Cells["uye_mailadresi"].Value.ToString();
}
```

*Codes on onclick event for Insert button*

```
private void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    baglan.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO uyeler (uye_adi,uye_soyadi,uye_yasi,uye_adresi,uye_telefonu,uye_mailadresi) values ('@uye_adi','@uye_soyadi','@uye_yasi','@uye_adresi','@uye_telefonu','@uye_mailadresi')",baglan);
    cmd.Connection = baglan;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_adi",textAd.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_soyadi",textSoyad.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_yasi",textYas.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_adresi",textAdres.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_telefonu",textTelefon.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_mailadresi",textMail.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    baglan.Close();
    listele();
}
```

Comment: Your value is in speech marks, so it is being inserted as text, what does uye_yasi actually contain? - it is most likely text

Comment: uye_yasi is an int column in my database.And I referenced it as @uye_yasi to textYas.Text(a textbox which contains age)

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_yasi",Convert.ToInt32(textYas.Text));   << this line does not work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your parameters with single quotes (e.g. '@uye_adresi') as .NET will handle performing that for you based on the types of the parameters that it identifies :

```
// Define your query and parameters
var query = "INSERT INTO uyeler (uye_adi,uye_soyadi,uye_yasi,uye_adresi,uye_telefonu,uye_mailadresi) VALUES (@uye_adi,@uye_soyadi,@uye_yasi,@uye_adresi,@uye_telefonu,@uye_mailadresi)";
```

Additionally, if you are planning on passing an integer value in as a parameter, consider converting it to the appropriate type beforehand using the [`Convert.ToInt32()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
// This will pass in your parameter as an integer
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_yasi",Convert.ToInt32(textYas.Text));
```

If this fails, then you might consider using the [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method that will allow to check if the data is a valid integer before continuing :

```
int age;
// Check if it is valid
if(!Int32.TryParse(textYas.Text, out age))
{
     // It was invalid, consider alerting the user and trying again
}
// Otherwise, it was valid and the proper age is stored in age, so use it
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uye_yasi",age);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!The problem was about,as you said,these single quotes.When I use them,It adds the text between single quotes(thats why it wasnt an int value).Now I can successfully represent my university project ;)